# java two sets of numbers in two fields of constructor?

Tags: java

I have been asked the following question.

> The class IntersectionSet also
>   implements the interface IntSet. An
>   instance of the class stores two sets.
>   The constructor takes two parameters
>   to initialise these two sets. The
>   method isElem implements the behaviour
>   of set intersection, that is, returns
>   true if and only if the given
>   parameter is an element of both sets.
>   Give the full definition of the class
>   IntersectionSet.

I have made the IntSet interface but am not sure how I can get two sets of two integers just from having two fields in the constructor. I have been successful with one set of two numbers from my previous class that I made.I will supply the Intset interface code and the other class I designed to create one set of numbers that I can check if the element is in there. Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
public class IntervallSet implements IntSet
{
    int lowerbound;
    int upperbound;

    public IntervallSet(int a, int b)
    {
        lowerbound = a;
        upperbound = b;
        if(a>b)
        {
            b = a;
            a = b;
        }
        else
        {
            a = a;
            b = b;
        }
    }

    public boolean isElem(int f)
    {
        if (f>= lowerbound && f<=upperbound)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not part of the original question, but your `IntervalSet` constructor is broken. The code you wrote to swap the values if a > b doesn't work, and even it it did you would have to swap them before assigning them to the lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 3):

The problem definition says:

> An instance of the class stores two
>   sets.

You will need to use `IntSet` for your storage and parameters instead of `int`:

```
IntSet set1, set2;

public IntersectionSet(IntSet a, IntSet b)
```

You can figure it out from here :-)